# How to resize dimension of LineChart (Reporting Services)

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have create a new report with Reporting Services. In this report I have a Line Chart (stacked column). It works, but now I want to change the size of one series of Chart. Is Possibile?

I want to change the with dimension on blue series. I would like to decrease the size of the column blue.

[image]

I would like to have a chart like this:

[image]

It is possibile?

Another question is: how I can to intersect the column blue and gray like as the second image?

Reguards

Comment: I have find a solution. Set this attribute PointWidth=0,5.